# Did Ludlum and the creators of 24 pay homage to Fleming in their choice of character names?

Tags: james-bond, 24, jason-bourne

James Bond, Jack Bauer, and Jason Bourne all have the same initials.

Coincidence or homage?

Comment: Homage or subtle inference of association?

Comment: I doubt it highly. But since you're asking the question, might as well throw **J**ack **B**ristow from Alias in there too.